# how do I perform an IMAP search based on a flag not being set

Tags: .net, imap

I'd like to be able to perform an IMAP search for messages that don't have the '/DELETED' flag set. The reason for this is that when I delete emails from my client, I carry out a 'soft' delete but the next time the client syncs to the server, it still returns the same message count including those with the '/DELETED' flag set.  I want to be able to perform a search on those emails which are not deleted.  I'm using the MailSystem.NET library to do this.

Do you have any ideas how I can get round this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about using UNDELETED search data item. Also you should read https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3501 , it will describe all search keys.

Comment: I used "NOT DELETED" in the end. I think the library I used didn't like UNDELETED when peforming searches using a certain method on their API.